# $AA^t=BB^t \implies A=B$

Tags: linear-algebra, transpose

Let $A$ and $B$ are complex valued $n\times n$ matrices and let $\det(A)=1$ or $-1$.

Then what necessary and sufficient conditions can be given for $A$ and $B$ to satisfy this proposition?

"If $AA^t=BB^t$, then $A=B$ or $A=-B$." where $A^t$ is the transpose of $A$.

Comment: How about n=1? .

Comment: @AnonymousCoward $n=1$ is clearly sufficient but don't you need to prove that it is necessary? OP asked for a necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: I'm suggesting that it might also be necessary.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward: I don't think it is. What about orthogonal matrices?

Comment: How about diagonal?

Comment: Simultaneously orthogonally diagonalizable?

Comment: @K.Miller: Since $\det(A) = \pm 1$ was assumed, the only orthogonal projection is the identity...

Comment: @user251257 Good point!

Comment: What precisely does OP mean by necessary here?  Let $F$ be the set of all the possible values of $AA^t$, and take $S$ to contain exactly one $\pm$ pair of preimages for each non-zero element of $F$ (together with the zero matrix).  Then for any choice of $S$, it is sufficient that $A,B \in S$ and each such $S$ is maximally inclusive.  But that doesn't make any one choice of $S$ **necessary**, as any other choice of $S$ would also suffice.

Comment: Since $A$ is complex, do you really mean $A^t$ or $A^*$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Warning and Notes:** I wrote the answer for *real* matrices and *transpose* $(\cdot)^t$. One can simply adapt it for *complex* matrices and *complex conjugate transpose*. However, complex matrices and only transpose is a complete other story...

In the question it is not clear, if the condition is on $(A,B)$, that is some logical formula $P(A,B)$, or the same condition is on $A$ and $B$, that is some logical formula $P(A) \land P(B)$. For the second case, there is no "solution" for $n>1$ (cf @ErickWong's comment to the question).

Now the results...

> **Claim 1:** The condition "$A,B$ are symmetric and definite" is sufficient to make
>   $$ AA^t = BB^t \implies A=B \lor A=-B$$
>   true.

*Proof:* First assume $A$ is positive definite. Then, $ AA^t = BB^t $ implies $I = A^{-1}B (A^{-1}B)^t$, that is $M = A^{-1}B$ is orthogonal. But $M$ is similar to $RMR^{-1} = R^{-1}BR^{-1}$, which is definite. That is, $M$ is either $I$ (in case $B$ is positive definite), or $-I$ (in case $B$ is negative definite). But that means $A = B$ or $A = -B$.

Now, assume $A$ is negative definite. Then, $\tilde A = -A$ is positive definite. Thus, by previous paragraph, we have $-A = B$ or $-A = -B$.

> **Claim 2:** Let 
>   $ M_0 = \{ A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n} : |\det A| = 1 \}, $
>   $ M_1 = \{ A\in M_0 : A \text{ symm. and definite} \}, $ 
>   and
>   $M_2 \subseteq M_0$ containing $M_1$ with the property 
>   $\forall A,B\in M_2: [AA^t = BB^t \implies A = B \lor A=-B]$.
>
> Then, $M_2 = M_1$.

*Proof:* Let $A\in M_2$. From $\tilde A = (AA^t)^{1/2}\in M_1 \subseteq M_2$ follows $A = \tilde A$ or $A = -\tilde A$. That is, $A$ is already in $M_1$. (thanks to @ErickWong)

Comment: Assuming that $t$ means "Hermitian", this is complete in the sense that $C=AA^t$ is always positive definite (by assumption $A$ is invertible) and therefore possesses a positive definite square root, which can serve as the representative of $C$ in your proposed set.  But i hesitate to call anything "necessary" as I comment above.

Comment: @ErickWong: You are right. I have expanded the answer and will ask op for clarification.