# Unique solution for $AA^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am doing this in $\mathbb{R}$. Given $A$ and $B$ are two square matrices so that $AA^T=BB^T$. I do not think it leads to $A=B$, but I cannot give a counterexample.

If not true generally, my further question is that: under what conditions, do we have $A=B$?

Thanks!

Comment: Related question: can you find two real numbers $a$ and $b$ (also known as $1\times1$ square matrices) such that $a^2=b^2$ but $a\neq b$?

Comment: 1^2 = (-1)^2. But I mean my question is for matrix of general dimension, at least 2.

Comment: @TDT, Matthew Leingang was hoping you would see the easy generalization, $B=-A$.

Comment: Yes, @Barry, that is also a solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, $AA^T=BB^T$ does not imply that $A=B$. Take $A=I_2$ and
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Because you said "but I cannot give a counterexample", let me say that taking matrices of size $2$ in many cases already gives a counterexample.

For the second question, this has been discussed already at MSE:

[$AA^t=BB^t \implies A=B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2075957/aat-bbt-implies-a-b)

Comment: Thanks! Can we have a general condition that it leads to $A=B$?

Comment: It depends what you mean by a general condition. For example, requiring $A=B$ is already such a condition. I suppose you want something less trivial, but it might be close to this.

Comment: Yes, something not that trivial solution.

Comment: One way would be to require the determinants of $A$ and $B$ be $\pm 1$, **and** that both are symmetric and definite. Pretty much, if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counter example.

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \cr 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$$ and $$B=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \cr 4 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$

Then $$AA^T =BB^T=\begin{bmatrix} 5 & 11 \cr 11 & 25 \end{bmatrix}$$

Other counter examples could be made by changing $1,2,3,4$ to arbitrary $a,b,c,d$